Java: How to disable logging for transitive dependencies but keep enabled for direct dependencies?
I am developing a Spring Boot application, where I will be using two dependencies -

Direct Apache kafka-clients
Another library that uses Apache kafka-clients internally

I want to adjust the logging levels for the kafka-clients which is added directly into my project but I want to turn off the logging for the kafka-clients that is added in the other library.
How can we achieve this?
If I add <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="off"/> then it is turning off logging for both the kafka-clients.

Are you using Java 9 modules or OSGi? If not, then there is absolutely no difference between a direct and transitive dependency: it's the same classes, loaded by the same classloader.

@kdgregory Nope, not using Java 9 modules or OSGi. So there is no way to manage the logging levels for same dependency that is being used in another library and in the direct project?

If you're using Logback you could use a filter to examine the stack trace of the logging event and discard those that don't come directly from your code. There's probably something similar for Log4J 2.x (and since you tagged this with both logback and log4j, I have no idea which you're using).

However, I think that's a lot of work for very little value. From an application monitoring standpoint, there should be no difference between calls to the Kafka library from your code and from third-party code: if either has problems, then your app has problems. I'm going to make an assumption that you're getting overwhelmed by low-level log messages, so if that's the case then the correct solution is to set the threshold level for Kafka to WARN or ERROR, and do the low-level logging in your application code, outside of the call to Kafka.
